i keep encountering this problem on my evee render mode

i keep encountering this problem on my blender evee render mode

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

That looks like a graphics driver problem to me. Make sure that your graphics card is supported in the version of Blender that you are using and that you have the latest graphics driver from the manufacturer installed.
